# Can I use mpiexec to run the same executable with different command line arguments for the executable each time?

Tags: mpi, spmd

I'm new to distributed operating system. And I need to train about multiple machine learning models with supercomputers. I need to run the same training script multiple times, and for each run passing the script with a different command line argument.  Can I achieve this by using mpiexec so that I can train multiple models in parallel with different inputs?

I found Single Program Multiple data model of mpi, but I don't know the corresponding commands.

I want to run the following line in parallel among the computation nodes in the cluster.

```
python train.py arg > log.out # arg is the argument that differs for each node
```

But, if I'm using:

```
mpiexec train.py arg >log.out
```

it would only run train.py with the same command line argument: arg for multiple times in parallel.

Can someone point out the right way to do it? Thank you!

Comment: check the comments in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52324857/running-mpiexec-with-different-script-parameters-for-each-process

Comment: Thank you, our current solution is using a shell script to submit all the similar jobs in a while loop, and passing a different argument to each of the executable of the job. It's kind similar to what the background processes did in this post.

Comment: Do you need any of the data from a `train.py` process to be shared with any other `train.py` process or are they all totally independent with only arg varied?

Comment: @EdSmith Each node shares part of the training data. But there's no dependency between the processed results of each node.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve what you want is to create a top level script, `mpi_train.py` using [mpi4py](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). In an MPI job, each process has a unique rank and all run the same code, so running,

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD

print("Hello! I'm rank " + str(comm.rank))
```

with

```
mpiexec -n 4 python mpi_train.py
```

will give

```
Hello! I'm rank 0
Hello! I'm rank 1
Hello! I'm rank 3
Hello! I'm rank 2
```

The different ranks can then be used to read a separate file which specifies the args. So you'd have something like,

```
#All code in train should be in functions or __name__ == "__main__"
import train
from mpi4py import MPI

def get_command_args_from_rank(rank):
     #Some code here to get args from unique rank no.

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD

args = get_command_args_from_rank(comm.rank)

#Assuming the args can be passed to a run function
out = train.run(args)
```

Note that you should explicitly specify the output for each process, with something like,

```
with open("log.out"+str(comm.rank)) as f:
    f.write(out)
```

otherwise all prints go to stdout and become jumbled as order of the various processes is not guaranteed.

Comment: this is a bit of an overkill **and** suboptimal since there could be some load imbalance, and `mpiexec` returns when the last rank completes (read: all other ranks might do nothing, and some MPI libs burn CPU doing that). Using a job array is IMHO way simpler and more efficient.

Comment: True, job arrays looks like a better solution for the OP, might be worth adding as an answer? Although isn't this a feature of PBS, not MPI? For load balancing, you could always add a loop over the `train.run` so each process is kept busy.

Comment: well, the point is `mpiexec` is not the best way to run simultaneously several instances of a serial program. and yes, Job Arrays is a feature of the Resource Manager (PBS, SLURM, LSF and others) and **not** MPI.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments and answers. Here is what I did to get to my final solution:

At first, I had a bash script to submit the job to the cluster as an array of jobs, with $PBS_ARRAYID to pass different command line argument to each job:

```
#PBS -N ondemand/sys/myjobs/default
#PBS -l walltime=24:10:00
#PBS -l file=1gb
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1:gpus=1:default
#PBS -l mem=40MB
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -A PAS0108
#PBS -o Job_array.out


# Move to the directory where the job was submitted
# run the following cmd in shell to submit the job in an array
# qsub -t 1-6 myjob.sh

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
cd $TMPDIR
# $PBS_ARRAYID can be used as a variable 

# copy data to local storage of the node
cp ~/code/2018_9_28_training_node_6_OSC/* $TMPDIR
cp -r ~/Datasets_1/Processed/PascalContext/ResNet_Output/ $TMPDIR
cp -r ~/Datasets_1/Processed/PascalContext/Truth/ $TMPDIR
cp -r ~/Datasets_1/Processed/PascalContext/Decision_Tree/ $TMPDIR

# currently in $TMPDIR, load modules
module load python/3.6 cuda
# using $PBS_ARRAYID as a variable to pass the corresponding node ID
python train_decision_tree_node.py $PBS_ARRAYID $TMPDIR  > training_log_${PBS_ARRAYID}

# saving logs
cp training_log ${HOME}/logs/${PBS_ARRAYID}_node_log/
cp my_results $PBS_O_WORKDIR
```

I submit the above script with command line:

```
qsub -t 1-6 myjob.sh
```

**But, I got an error from the cluster,** somehow the local directory `$TMPDIR` can't be recognized by the actual node in the cluster when I run the script.

Finally, what I did is that I use a top level bash script to submit each job with a different command line argument in a while loop and it worked:

**run_multiple_jobs.tcsh:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env tcsh
set n = 1
while ( $n <= 5 )
    echo "Submitting job for concept node $n"
    qsub -v NODE=$n job.pbs
    @ n++
end
```

**jobs.pbs:**

```
#PBS -A PAS0108
#PBS -N node_${NODE}
#PBS -l walltime=160:00:00
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1:gpus=1
#PBS -l mem=5GB
#PBS -m ae
#PBS -j oe

# copy data
cp -r ~/Datasets/Processed/PascalContext/Decision_Tree $TMPDIR
cp -r ~/Datasets/Processed/PascalContext/Truth $TMPDIR
cp -r ~/Datasets/Processed/PascalContext/ResNet_Output $TMPDIR

# move to working directory
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR

# run program
module load python/3.6 cuda/8.0.44
python train_decision_tree_node.py ${NODE} $TMPDIR $HOME

# run with run_multiple_jobs.tcsh script
```